# 'GeneratorContextManager' Object does not support indexing

Tags: python, python-2.7, object

I am trying to load `.p12` certificate by converting it into `pem` cert and key as found through this [github source](https://gist.github.com/erikbern/756b1d8df2d1487497d29b90e81f8068)

My code looks like this

```
@contextlib.contextmanager
def pfx_to_pem(pfx_path, pfx_password):
    ''' Decrypts the .pfx file to be used with requests. '''
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.pem') as t_pem:
        f_pem = open(t_pem.name, 'wb')
        pfx = open(pfx_path, 'rb').read()
        p12 = OpenSSL.crypto.load_pkcs12(pfx, pfx_password)
        f_pem.write(OpenSSL.crypto.dump_privatekey(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, p12.get_privatekey()))
        f_pem.write(OpenSSL.crypto.dump_certificate(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, p12.get_certificate()))
        ca = p12.get_ca_certificates()      
        if ca is not None:
            for cert in ca:
                f_pem.write(OpenSSL.crypto.dump_certificate(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, cert))
        f_pem.close()       
        yield t_pem.name

cert = pfx_to_pem(clientCert,password)
```

when I execute this, I keep getting an error that says

```
  File "F:\code\InforSTS\scripts\loadDefaultDataV2.py", line 87, in <module>
    res4 = requests.get(gridEndpoint,headers = headers, cert=cert, verify=False)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 72, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 58, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 518, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 639, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 405, in send
    self.cert_verify(conn, request.url, verify, cert)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 240, in cert_verify
    conn.cert_file = cert[0]
TypeError: 'GeneratorContextManager' object does not support indexing
```

How do I get a certificate from this `cert` object? It is clear that it is not an array.

Comment: Did you read the "HOW TO USE" part right beneath the code you copied?

Comment: Got it ...my bad in reading that how to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a [@contextmanager](https://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager), which handles the temporary file deletion for you. But one should use it with `with`:

```
with pfx_to_pem(clientCert, password) as cert:
    requests.get(url, cert=cert)
```